# Progress ring in async Thread with MahApps.Metro

Tags: wpf, vb.net, tags, microsoft-metro

I want to open in async thread a wpf window (Window1.xaml) with ProgressRing.
When the window constructor is called the exception appears: "the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".

The windows:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:metro="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    <metro:ProgressRing Name="myring" ></metro:ProgressRing>
</Grid>
```

The thread is run by the class Attesa:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Threading
Imports MahApps.Metro.Controls

Public Class Attesa
    Implements IDisposable

Private _sender As Object
Private newDialog As DialogAttesa
Private test As Window1
Private oAvvia As Threading.Thread
Private Delegate Sub ChiudiFormDelegate()

Public Sub New()
    Avvio()
End Sub

Private disposedValue As Boolean ' Per rilevare chiamate ridondanti

Public Property Sender As Object
    Get
        Return _sender
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        _sender = value
    End Set
End Property

' IDisposable
Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not disposedValue Then
        If disposing Then
            Chiusura()
        End If
    End If
    disposedValue = True
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    ' Non modificare questo codice. Inserire il codice di pulizia in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean).
    Dispose(False)
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub

' Questo codice è aggiunto da Visual Basic per implementare in modo corretto il modello Disposable.
Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    ' Non modificare questo codice. Inserire il codice di pulizia in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean).
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub Avvio()
    oAvvia = New Thread(AddressOf ApriForm)
    oAvvia.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    oAvvia.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub ApriForm()
    test = New Window1()
    test.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub Chiusura()
    ChiudiForm()
End Sub

Private Sub ChiudiForm()
    While test Is Nothing
    End While

    If test.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() Then
        test.Close()
        test = Nothing
    Else
        test.Dispatcher.Invoke(New ChiudiFormDelegate(AddressOf ChiudiForm))

    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

When I use the class in my project:

```
  Using a As Attesa = New Attesa()
        'something to do
    End Using`
```

the exception appears: "the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to do GUI stuff asynchronously. That kinda defeats the purpose of a GUI.

Comment: I want to use the window as a wait window, while running a job in the main thread

Comment: A 'wait window' is still a window; if you want your progress ring to animate, it has to be on the UI thread, and your job has to run asynchronously.

Comment: I have already tried this solution and it works correctly. But it's not the right solution for me.

Comment: I really don't want to read VB, so I can't help you further than that unless you clarify your need; but these are kind of absolute rules when it comes to user interfaces. At worst, you can execute the job on the UI thread, but it will freeze the UI. But running the UI asynchronously doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: The same strategy with a different component as a metro: progressbar works correctly